# Mysql Left Join for table of sales by month with empty months

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, left-join

I need to make a report with total sales for the month, with a zero value for months with no sales. This is the query I am working with so far, and I feel like I have tried every combination with no luck. I need the months in 1 array and the sales for each month in another array for my report purposes.

query:

```
$productSql = "SELECT months.monthnum, SUM(orders.total) FROM months LEFT JOIN orders ON months.monthnum = MONTH(orders.closeddate) WHERE orders.status = 'Closed' GROUP BY MONTH(orders.closeddate) ORDER BY months.monthnum ASC";
$productResult = mysql_query($productSql, $link);

while($productRow = mysql_fetch_array($productResult)){

$label[] = $productRow['months.monthnum'];
$data[] = $productRow['SUM(orders.total)'];
};

echo "[".json_encode($label).",".json_encode($data)."]";
```

Result:

```
[[null,null],["6000.00","3100.00"]]
```

How do I get it to show all months in the first array, and zero's for the months with no sales in the second array? I think its the GROUP BY that's killing me, but i need that to add up the sales. Help!

PS I know I should discontinue using mysql and I will as soon as this project is finished. Thanks!

**EDIT**

var_dump results:

```
array(1) { [0]=> NULL } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "6000.00" } array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL } array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "6000.00" [1]=> string(7) "3100.00" }
```

**EDIT 2**

SO the problem is in the WHERE clause. I need the where clause because I only want orders that are closed. When I take the WHERE clause out it shows all months with zero for months with no sales and correctly sums the months that do have sales. However it is including ALL orders, not just closed orders. Where do I put the WHERE clause so that I still get all months?

Comment: Do you already have all tne months in the db?IF not you need a month table,esentially 12 ints.

Comment: Any tip why is it returning null values  for monthnum column? Doesn´t make sense at all

Comment: not possible unless you have a table that contains all of the relevant months already that you can join again. SQL doesn't allow for records to be created out of thin air like that. if you don't have a "march" somewhere, you won't get "march" in the output. There are non-standard extensions that DO let particular DBs generate record sequences (e.g. sequential dates), but they're non-standard and therefore non-portable.

Comment: @Mihai yes, the months table has one column with the month numbers, 1-12 and one column with the month names.

Comment: @sergio0983 I think it is the group by that is screwing that up, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MarcB The months table contains all 12 months, the numerical representation, and the name.

Comment: You need to GROUP BY MONTH,YEAR,if you have more than 1 year.

Comment: Your query is working. do a `var_dump($row)` to see what you're really getting out of the db.

Comment: You are doing a _GROUP BY MONTH(orders.closeddate)_, but on a month with no orders that will be null. You need to _GROUP BY months.monthnum_ instead.

Comment: Put the check for _orders.status = 'Closed'_ into the ON clause of the JOIN rather than the WHERE clause. That will exclude the rows prior to the join rather than after the join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the zero values using the following query:

```
SELECT m.monthnum, coalesce(SUM(o.total), 0)
FROM months m LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON m.monthnum = MONTH(o.closeddate) AND o.status = 'Closed'
GROUP BY m.monthnum
ORDER BY m.monthnum ASC";
```

There are three significant changes:

- The comparison to `o.status` is moved to the `on` clause.
- The aggregation uses the `months` table rather than the `orders` table.
- The total uses `coalesce()` to get 0 rather than `NULL`.

I also introduced table aliases, which makes queries easier to write and to read.

Comment: this returned null for both arrays :( I don't understand why it is not showing all the months if I am left joining the orders table to the months table.